# CSS3 curved cutout from div?

Tags: css

Is there a way to create a cutout in a `div` with `CSS3` like in the example below?

[image]

What I'm trying to do is create a cutout in between 2 `divs` as the image. The actual `div` that is being cut out is the `div` at the bottom, it has a `background-color`, a `drop shadow`, `inset shadow` and a `border style`.

What I would like to do then is put a `CSS3` button inside the cutout of the `div`.

Comment: Can it be done using only css??? I doubt it.

Comment: Have you considered using SVG or Canvas for this - CSS is capable of some good stuff, but even if you can get this working in CSS, it would be stretching it to the limit, and you'll likely get serious browser compatibility issues as a result. Doing the graphic in SVG or Canvas will be much easier, and give you much better cross-browser compatibility (there are even hacks for old IE to get it to support SVG and Canvas).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT - NEW Solution**

with `radial-gradient`, it is possible to achieve new levels of quality in cutout divs: <kbd>[**Running Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/tUHZW/)</kbd>

Read more on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18853833/1654265

---

**OLD Solution**

You can do it with an homogeneus background, not with an artistic one like your. There are things that CSS will never do, for example becoming Photoshop.

However, you can do the trick using borders, negative margin and z-index;

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cB8Qq/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="rounded">bla bla bla</div>
        <div class="digged"> <br/><br/>or yada yada yada </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;    
}

.rounded{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background: silver;    
    padding: 10px;    
    border: 10px solid #ddd;    
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.digged{    
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: silver;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -30px
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) P.S: Nice Ascii Art in your profile, but you need to add an 'n' to your java hello printing ^^

Comment: Thank you! Sure, it's `println`. Fixed it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to simplfiy your design, but a similar effect is possible using gradients and pseudo-elements.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ouKCq)

```
body{background: salmon;}
.main {background:gray; width:300px; height:200px; position: relative; margin-top:20px;}
.main:after, .main:before{content:''; width: 50px; height: 20px; background: inherit; position: absolute; }
.main:after{ top:-20px; left:0;}
.main:before{ top:-20px; right:0;}

.phone{width:175px; height:40px; background: gray; margin-left:62.5px; border-radius: 50px; text-align: center; line-height: 40px; position: relative;}

.phone:after,.phone:before{content:''; width:20px; height:20px; background:red; position: absolute;}

.phone:before{bottom:-20px; left:-12px; background: -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 20px, gray 15px);}
.phone:after{bottom:-20px; left:168px; background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 20px, gray 15px);}
```