# CSS oval shape cut out from div

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

[image: goal]

The above image is what i'm trying to create but am having some difficulties with the oval shape. An explanation:

- The menu bar is a div with a slight linear gradient (dark grey to transparent lighter grey)
- The company logo image has a transparent bg and will sit 'ontop' of the menu bar
- The oval cutout will need to match the oval of the logo and have a transparent gap between that will show the background colour (this changes on each page, orange is just an example)

I've tried and failed many times with a radial gradient - I was able to get a circle cut out but couldn't work out how to make it oval and then couldn't get the linear gradient to work. See code:

```
.circle {
    height: 10em;
    background: radial-gradient(circle 50px at 50% 100%, transparent 50px, rgba(84, 82, 94, 0.8) 50px);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 100%, circle, transparent 50px, rgba(84, 82, 94, 0.8) 50px);
}
```

When the cutout shape and the gradient is sorted, the logo will be positioned over the top.

Any suggestions or jsfiddle solutions would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JazParkyn/fZWM4/)

EDIT 2: Have solved the problem by changing the design slightly, thanks to those who replied. I wrote some jquery to solve this - when the coloured area scrolls out of view the oval border and header border will pick up the colour of the top section, instead of the transparency.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14747815/1654265

Comment: I've retracted the close-vote. And +1, actually what you tried was source of inspiration :)

Comment: Good to hear - and thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start from this <kbd>[**Running Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/tUHZW/)</kbd>

Note: I've added a small animation to change the background color just to clear that the space between the island and the div with the cutout is *really* transparent.

HTML

```
<div class="cutout">
    <div class="island">
        <div id="circleText">Circle Text </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cutout {
    height: 10em;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse 200px 150px at 50% 100%, 
                                transparent 100px, #555 50px);
    position: relative;
}
.island {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 150px);
    bottom: -50%;
    width: 300px;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse 200px 150px at 50% 50%, 
                                silver 90px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50px);
    height: 10em;
}
.island > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    right: 80px;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;

    background: rgba(fff, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 5px;    
    text-align: center;    
}

#circleText {
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Can you change your answer so that one can add shadow inside the curve?

Comment: @AmiNadimi just use box-shadow ;) and upvote if it helped

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 100%, transparent 50px, rgba(84, 82, 94, 0.8) 50px);
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/grv7n/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

position it absolutely on top of the other parts of the menu

Comment: Yes, I've found that webpage useful before, but the shape needs to be a cutout - and transparent. Thanks though

Comment: oh, sorry. i misunderstood the question

Comment: What if you created a div with the same color as the background, positioned it where you want the cutout and then place another div on top of it with the logo?

Comment: The background colour will change as the page scrolls, so it does need to be a cut out

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
.container{
    height: 10em;
    background: #76757e;
}

.ovalCutout{
    background:white;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    top:120px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UwXKu/

Comment: Good idea, but as the background colour will change as the page scrolls, it needs to be a cutout with transparency. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

You can do it making a composite of 3 backgrounds, the center one radial and the side ones linear.

It's difficult however to make the 2 kind of gradients match exactly; it will be only doable if the gradient is very smooth.

```
.back {
    height: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(200px 100px ellipse at 50% 100%, transparent 70px, 
               rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8) 73px, 
               rgba(80, 80, 80, 1) 198px), 
    linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(80, 80, 80), rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8)), 
    linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(80, 80, 80), rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8));
    background-size: 200px 100px, 40% 100%, 40% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 50%, 0%, 100%;
    background-position-y: 100%;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/GZVCy/)

Comment: Your code breaks in firefox, the oval cutout gets filled by a gradient; thanks for answering.