# Curved button corners

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm looking for options to create buttons like these:

[image: Screenshot]

Currently, I have been able to achieve the effect shown by creating a circular mask that sits under the logo and the background below that, but over the buttons. This does, however, cause problems when trying to make the navigation fixed to the top.

Is it possible to create buttons like this without a mask, possibly using a border-radius?

This is what I have so far:

```css
/* Navigation */

#logo {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: -172px auto;
  border: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
  z-index: 3;
}
#logo:active {
  top: 2px;
}
#logo-mark {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 96px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: .25s;
  transition: .25s;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#logo-mark:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#nav-mask {
  background-color: #ececec;
  position: relative;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 200px;
  z-index: 0;
}
#nav-wrapper {
  background-color: #ececec;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
#nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 90px;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #494f4f;
  height: 50px;
  width: 130px;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: .25s;
  transition: .25s;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 0;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #3c4141;
  opacity: 1;
}
.btn:active {
  background-color: #3c4141;
}
.btn-left {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
.btn-right {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
.btn-rightmost {
  text-align: right;
}
.text-nav {
  color: #fff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 10px 8px 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-wrapper">
  <div id="nav">
    <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-left">
      <h3 class="text-nav">About</h3>
    </a>
    <a href="#work" class="btn btn-right">
      <h3 class="text-nav">Work</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="nav-mask"></div>
<a href="website">
  <div id="logo">
    <img id="logo-mark" src="http://www.placehold.it/96">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: How this get upvotes? ... Please show us what you have tried and the code HTML & CSS

Comment: Multiple accounts probably?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830868/css-oval-shape-cut-out-from-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on your design using [`:before` and `:after` pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and the minimum HTML required. It uses the masking concept, but it wont break.

[image: Screenshot]

### The Curve

The curve on the two buttons is created with an `:after` pseudo element of the nav. The circle is cut off with `overflow: hidden` on the nav. It is positioned with `position: absolute` and will not shift from its position.

The nav is given `position: relative` so that the circle will position itself in relation with it.

It looks like this:

[image: Mask]

### Positioning the links

The links are pushed apart with padding. Without the pseudo element mask, they look like this:

[image: Links Positioning]

### Positioning the logo

The image is given `position: absolute` and is positioned with `left: 50%` and a negative margin of half its width, including border, to bring it dead center.

The header is given `position: relative` so that the logo will position itself in relation with it.

### Vertical centering

The *links* are centered using `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`. This works thanks to the `:before` pseudo element vertical centering trick.  This brings inline elements in line and looks like this:

```
header nav:before {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The *text* is centered in the links using `line-height: 50px` which matches the links `height: 50px`.

### Inline gaps

Inline gaps are prevented by leaving no whitespace between the inline elements, like so:

```
  <nav><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Work</a></nav>
```

[Here is a write-up on preventing this gap over on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

### Complete Examples

#### Fixed Width

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  background: #EEE;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  position: relative;
  width: 377px;
}
header nav {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header nav:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  margin-left: -85px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #EEE;
}
header nav a {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #666;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav a:first-child {
  padding: 0 100px 0 20px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
header nav a:last-child {
  padding: 0 20px 0 100px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 5px #FFF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Work</a></nav>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/130" />
</header>
```

#### 100% width and centered

- Instead of a width, the header is allowed to take up 100% of the width thanks to `display: block` (its default value)
- Everything is centered inside the header with `text-align: center`

[image: 100% width Screenshot]

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  background: #EEE;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header nav:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  margin-left: -85px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #EEE;
}
header nav a {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #666;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav a:first-child {
  padding: 0 100px 0 20px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
header nav a:last-child {
  padding: 0 20px 0 100px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 5px #FFF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav><a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Work</a></nav>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/130" />
</header>
```

Comment: This is done using a mask, but it will have no problem being `position: fixed` as the mask is contained completely within the `<nav>` and becomes more like a background :)

Comment: This totally works, thanks a bunch!

Just a silly question though: Could you perhaps tell me how to make the navbar cover the entire width of the page and center it?

Comment: @PaulVO - Easy :D Remove the width on the header and give it `text-align: center`. I have added a second example in my answer for you :)

Comment: I also somehow managed to place the CSS in twice for my examples. I removed the excess so there are no duplicate selectors :)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Is there any way I can add more buttons to the bar? They seem to get covered up underneath the logo mark.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/hotuha/1/edit?css,output). The center links have been made position absolute and the link just before "About" has a class (`.centerLeft`) which pushes the links on the right out from underneath the centered links. Experiment with this idea :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}

figure{
    width: 480px;
    height:320px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    background: red
}

img{
    z-index:2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #E4E4E4;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 14px 0 #333,0 0 0 4px white, 0 0 18px #333;
}

figcaption{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #E4E4E4;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.34);
}
figcaption div{
    line-height: 65px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 178px;
    height: 64px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
figcaption div:nth-of-type(1),figcaption div:nth-of-type(2){
    border-radius: 4px; 
}
figcaption div:nth-of-type(1){
    text-indent: 36px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left   
}
figcaption div:nth-of-type(2){
    text-indent: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: right  
}
figcaption div:nth-of-type(1):before,figcaption div:nth-of-type(2):before{
    z-index: -2;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 116px;
    height: 164px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 400px #444
}
figcaption div:nth-of-type(1):before{
    right: -61px;
    bottom: -100px
}
figcaption div:nth-of-type(2):before{
    left: -61px;
    bottom: -100px
}
figcaption a{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    z-index: 999999999999;
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="" />
    <figcaption>
        <div><a>About</a></div>
        <div><a>Work</a></div>
    <figcaption>   
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/56axt9z0/1/

You just have to overlap a few `div`'s that have a `border-radius` equal to half of their `width`/`height` to get a circular `div`.

Comment: You should your code in your answer. You may also want to consider making use of the code snippet functionality now available in Stack Overflow. At the moment your answer makes little sense without visiting an external resource